# Копирование символа(части) строки C++

Tags: c++, строки

Как из строки char str1[100] скопировать в строку char str2[1] символ под номером i? Или часть строки от char str1[N] до char str1[M] в строку char str3[100]? Допустим нужно сделать программу, которая переворачивает строку(было "1234", стало "4321"). В паскале существует функция copy, с которой все легко реализовать, подскажите такую функцию(если она есть) в c++

Comment: скопировать символ - это же просто - `str2[0] = str1[i]`. И да, строка в один символ.. может лучше просто char?

Answer (score 1):

[strncpy](http://all-ht.ru/inf/prog/c/func/strncpy.html) в помощь. Но, раз уж вы программируете на `c++` лучше все-таки пользовать стандартным классом `string`, либо пометьте вопрос как `c`.

Comment: Не подскажите, как копировать при помощи ctrncpy с n-ого символа, т. к. я понимаю strncpy копирует от начала до n-ого символа?

Comment: да, все верно, он копирует от начала до n-ого символа... если хотите скопировать с определенного символа - просто установите туда "начало"

Comment: strncpy(str3,str1[m],n)? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @profy нет. Вам бы сначала про указатели почитать, прежде чем с ними работать. Вы же не будете брать в руки бензопилу и бить по ней в надежде на то что она включится) Второй параметр у вас просто символ char а не указатель на него (если это, конечно не двумерный массив char а одномерный)